# Which format should I use to store dates and times in an Android App SQLite Database, such that I can use them to plot a graph?

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime, types

I am writing an Android app where I would like the user to track values over time, store them in an SQLite database and plot a graph using an MPAndroid line chart.

According to https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html, there are several acceptable ways to store dates/times in an SQLite database:

- **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Furthermore, it appears that there is more than one way to store and access dates in Java. The format should be compatible with using date/time picker or current date/time functions.

Which format / combination of formats in SQLite and Android would be most suitable for my application?

Cheers, Oli

Comment: according your data if your data is integer then Integer other wise Text .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you will get better results if you use a framework over a bare sqlite database, such as [Room persistence library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html). It can serialize dates for you.

In case you want to use sqlite3 types, ISO8601 as TEXT and timestamp as INTEGER are good to go. Just advise you that, if you are going to deal with dates in java, in case that you aren't using Java 8, you better use [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/) or [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).